# HtmlResponse working in Scrapy Shell, but not in script?

Tags: python, scrapy

I'm using scraperAPI.com to handle IP rotation for a scraping job I'm working on and I'm trying to implement their new post request method, But I keep receiving a 'HtmlResponse' object has no attribute 'dont_filter' error. Here is the custom start_requests function:

```
def start_requests(self):
    S_API_KEY = {'key':'eifgvaiejfvbailefvbaiefvbialefgilabfva5465461654685312165465134654311'
             }
    url = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXX.com"
    payload={}
    headers = {
       'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8',
       'x-requested-with': 'XMLHttpRequest',
       'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
       'accept': 'application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01',
       'referer': 'XXXXXXXXXXX.com'
       }
    client = ScraperAPIClient(S_API_KEY['key'])
    resp = client.post(url = url, body = payload, headers = headers)
    yield HtmlResponse(resp.url, body = resp.text,encoding = 'utf-8')
```

The weird part is that when I execute this script piecewise in scrapy shell it works fine and returns the proper data, Any insight into this issue would be GREATLY appreciated? currently 4 hours into this problem.

#### Notes:

- Client.post returns a response object
- Not my real API key
- client.post doesn't have a body method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you get is caused by returning the wrong type (a Response).
From the docs for [`start_requests`](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html#scrapy.spiders.Spider.start_requests):

> This method must return an iterable with the first Requests to crawl for this spider.

It seems the easiest solution would be using a scrapy request (probably a `FormRequest`) to the API url, instead of using `ScraperAPIClient.post()`.
You should be able to use `ScraperAPIClient.scrapyGet()` to generate the correct url, but I have not tested this.

If you would prefer to continue using the official api library, a slightly more complicated option is [Writing your own downloader middleware](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/downloader-middleware.html#writing-your-own-downloader-middleware).